# How can I change an object's attributes with function?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, object, attributes

Forgive me if the title isn't specific enough. Let's say I want to make an RPG. I make a class for the characters. I then make an array that function as a party of characters. Then I have a function that reduced the HP of the first member of a party.

`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Chara
    {
    public:
        int HP;
        Chara(int health)
        {
            HP = health;
        }
    };

int Battle(Chara Party[2])
    {
        Party[0].HP -= 2;
    }

int main()
{
    Chara Final(0);
    Chara Fantasy(7);

    Chara Player[2] = {Final, Fantasy};

    Battle(Player);
    std::cout << Final.HP;
}
```

`

However, the HP of the character doesn't change. Is there something that I can do to make it so that the character's HP actually changes?

Comment: `int Battle(...)` — perhaps you meant: `void Battle(...)` with parameter as a pass-by-reference.

Comment: Note that your `Battle` was done on the array called `Player`, so any changes will only be reflected on elements in that array, not `Final` or `Fantasy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate problems caused by C++ passing structs by copy.

First, the line `Chara Player[2] = {Final, Fantasy};` creates an array of `Chara` and initializes the members with *copies* of the mentioned variables. That means that the final line will not see any modifications made to elements of `Player`.
Instead, you should do:

```
Chara Player[2] = { Chara{0}, Chara{7} };
// and optionally, if you still want to access individual members:
Chara& Final = Player[0];
Chara& Fantasy = Player[1];
```

Secondly, you pass `Player` to the `Battle` function by copy. Thus, any changes made to `Party` inside the function are not reflected in the outer `Player` variable.
The quick fix is to take `Party` by pointer instead:

```
void Battle(Chara* Party) { ... }
```

This works because arrays can decay to pointers to their first element when passed.

As best practice, you should probably use a `std::vector` instead, which allows you to dynamically add and remove party members and has all kinds of helpful methods.

Comment: Did you mean in the declaration: `Chara Player[2] = { Chara {0}, Chara {7} }`?

Comment: Yes, thanks for spotting that.

Comment: Crystal clear. +1